# Call java method in javascript without html firebug extension

Tags: java, javascript, applet, firebug

I'm trying to develop an extension for firebug. I want to call a java method in this extension but there is no html in it so I can't use the applet-html solution.

Here is my java Applet :

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyApplet extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        super.init();
        System.out.println("init something");
    }

    public String jsCall(String hello) {
        System.out.println("this method is called by a js function and say :"
                + hello);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                JOptionPane jop1 = new JOptionPane();
                jop1.showMessageDialog(null, "Message informatif", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);     
            }
        });
        t.start();

        return "lala";
    }

}
```

I try this:

```
var applet = document.createElement("applet");
applet.setAttribute("code","file:///home/dacostam/z_test/firebug-extension-examples-0bdcf15/helloamd@janodvarko.cz/chrome/content/MyApplet.class");
applet.setAttribute("id","javaToJavascriptApplet");
applet.setAttribute("mayscript","true");
applet.jsCall("HelloWorld"); //jsCall not a function
```

And this:

```
var dom = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
dom.appendChild(applet);
dom.javaToJavascriptApplet.jsCall("HelloWorld"); //jsCall not a function
```

The document is not like usual there is no body or html in it.

Is there an other way to call java in javascript instead of the applet-html solution?
Or is there a way to do it with this method but otherwise?

If you need more information, I'm here.

Thanks.

Edit:

It would be to long to explain you what the program do, just keep in mind that it's inevitably in java, I just need to call a method which take a parameter string and return a string or eventually void.

Edit2:

Sorry I have not thought of that, java needs to run on the client.

Comment: If there's no applet, what Java do you intend to be calling to?

Comment: Could you give a description of what you are trying to ultimately accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to make a call from JavaScript to your Java application, you need to clarify where does your Java app needs to run.

If Java needs to run on the client (same machine as your Firebug), it looks like you are either stuck with an applet or you need to be building a tiny webservice in your Java so you can talk to it through a web API on localhost.

If your Java can sit on a server somewhere, you could talk to your Java application through a web API (similarly to the second option above).

Comment: So like I said, I see two options for client side: applet and a standalone app with a tiny web frontend, so you can fire localhost http requests to it.

Comment: The second option is possible, it's sure it will work but it is quite demanding.

Comment: Hi, I made a lot of research and it seems that your solution, it's the eaiest way to do it. So I search how to do a webservice in Java but the solution are too complcated. Do you know a tutorial to do a simple java webservice.

Comment: I found this : http://nikojava.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/a-simple-web-service-in-java/

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I meant service in a normal sense of this word not in the modern "webservices" sense. In essense you need a server socket listening on a high enough port (e.g. like 12888) and then being able to handle your requests/give you back responses. It's not the simplest, nor quickest solution, but so aren't your requirements.

Comment: @makismov It's what I understand in my first reading but I didn't succeed to do it so I try an other way. I know how to do a socket server with Java but how to do a client Javascript to communicate with the server. I found the websocket method but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thank's, I don't know how to receive data in javascript with this method but I found a way to do it without that.